# Get array value in html by knockoutjs

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am getting value from an array like below:

```
self.users = ko.computed(function(){
var list = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.tasks(), function(item){
return item.members + item.skype
});
var val = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(list);
alert(val);
return val;});
```

Its showing values like:

```
user1skype_user1, user2skype_user2
```

But my problem is i need to show this value in html inside foreach loop of users. My html code is below:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
<tr>
 <td>
  <b><span data-bind="text: //membername" /></b>
 </td>
 <td>
  <span data-bind="text : //skypeid"></span>
 </td>
 </tr>
//another fareach loop</tbody>
```

I have created jsfiddle by taking another appraoch. but its repeating according to tasknos.
[jsfiddle in another approach](http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/8/)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Can you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have posted jsfiddle for it

Comment: Yes I saw that but don't understand what you are asking.  Specifically: "i need to show this value in html inside foreach loop of users"

Comment: Do you want to collect the users that circulating in the foreach into the list?

Comment: I see your updated fiddle in the update/answer below.  It looks like it's working.  Is it not working in the way you want?  Can you help us understand how you want it to work differently?  It might help if you can say something like 'The resulting HTML looks like XXX but I want the resulting HTML to look like YYY in my fiddle'.

Comment: I need like this http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/9/, but i have done it by writing javascript function. I need it using some knockoutjs technique if possible.

Answer (score 0):

My need was to get single set of users whatever the no of task will be.
I have added an javascript function to get single set of user and put it in self.users.
I have updated in my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TQXja/9/

```
self.users = ko.computed(function(){
var distinctUsers = "";
var distinctList = new Array();;

var list = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.tasks(), function(item){
    if(distinctUsers.indexOf("|"+ item.members) == -1)
    {
        distinctUsers += "|"+ item.members;
        return item;
    }
});

//clean empty objects
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    if(list[i] != null)
    {
        distinctList.push(list[i]);
    }
}

return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(distinctList);});
```

And now its working.